# converting input type text to plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm working on a small html form with 1 textbox input, after the user enters any text and he presses a button on the end of the page i want the  to change to a normal plain html text(so the whole page can be copy pasted into a word file including the written down text in the textbox).

as an example:

```
<input type="text" id="fileserver">
<button onclick="disable_all();">click!</button>
```

after the button is pressed i want the textbox to be converted to plain html text with no more textbox like this:

this is an example text after pressing the button!

click!

i have been searching around and have not found a working solution yet, hope someone can help me out

Comment: Thank you all for the great solutions provided, they all work and i will try the last ones tomorrow and see wich one works best. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it I think.

```
function disable_all() {
 var fs =  $("#fileserver"), span = $( "<span>" + fs.val() + "</span>");
 span.insertAfter(fs);
 fs.remove(); // or fs.hide(); in case you want it later.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('body *').replaceWith(function(){
        return this.value || this.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYw9P/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fileserver">
<button id="but">click!</button>
```

JS:

```
$( "#but" ).click(function() {
     var text=$( "#fileserver" ).val();
     $( "body" ).html(text);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gmh6z/)

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful to you -

There are several way to achieve your task :

**Solutions 1 -**

```
function disable_all()
{
    $('#content').remove();
    $('#fileserver, button').hide();
    $('body').append("<div id='content'>" + $('#fileserver').val() + "</div>")
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4P7Wj/)

**Solution 2 -**

```
function disable_all()
{
   $("body").html($("#fileserver").val());
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4P7Wj/1/)

Comment: thank you all guys, they all seem to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this hiding the textbox

```
<input type="text" id="fileserver">
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="btn" >click!</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result").hide();  
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#result").text($("#fileserver").val());
        $("#fileserver").hide();
        $("#result").show();
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XDvDf/)

Answer (score 1):

The first "non-jQuery" answer...

your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fileserver">
<div style="display: none;" id="fileserver_text"></div>
<button id="btn">click!</button>
```

your Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = disable_all;
function disable_all() {
    var input = document.getElementById('fileserver');
    var disp = document.getElementById('fileserver_text')
    disp.innerHTML = input.value; // get the text from the input and set the div text
    disp.style.display = 'block'; // show the div
    input.style.display = 'none'; // hide the input
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lneeg/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQUery, this will help you, 
http://jsfiddle.net/DCak6/

```
function save(){
    $('input,textarea').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.after('<span class="value">' + $this.val() + '</span>');
        $this.remove();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off with taking the text from the text field, copying the value and putting it into another div

```
<div id="textToCopy"></div>
<input type="text" id="fileserver">
<button onclick="disable_all();">click!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disable_all() { 
        $('#textToCopy').html($('#fileserver').val());
        $('#fileserver').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i'm going to try this tomorrow and get back to you, i'm chcking all solutions posted here, thank you again!